# What is the difference in below code pieces?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have two solutions, what is the difference between them?

Solution 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.println(" * ");
      }
      System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
```

Solution 2:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int num = 0;
    while (num < 5) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + "*" + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
      num++;
    }
  }
```

Both are printing different results. Can anybody please explain why?

Answer (score 6):

Well, the first snippet uses `System.out.println` in the inner loop, so every String is printed in a separate line. The second snippet uses `System.out.print` in the inner loop, and only moves to the next line after the inner loop ends.

In addition, the first snippet skips two lines after it finishes the inner loop, and the second snippet only ends the current line (`System.out.println("\n");` vs. `System.out.print("\n");`).

Changing each `println` to `print` in the first snippet should produce the same output as the second snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out just the moment I put this up :D But thanks for the efforts to write it down in such neat manner :)